# Share two internet connections in the home network

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

I am new to networking, my problem is: I have two internet connections in my company, so when one internet goes down, it should access from another – but it's not working: the Internet is connected to different routers and then connected to a switch. If I want to share Internet connections, what setting do I want to change on the computers or router?

I tried the following settings on the computers (Windows 7):

1. Set the default gateway & preferred DNS as first internet
2. Set alternative DNS as second internet
3. Added the second internet connection IP in the "default gateway" option in the "advanced" tab of network adapter settings.

Comment: Take a look at this; https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy might be what you're looking for.

Comment: At the title you said it's a home network and then you said it a company.
You know, size does matter...
You wouldn't want to run with Unnikrishnan's idea if you have more than 10 stations...
Anyway, I do think that STTR's idea is better, setting metric value for each network interface.
And just to make it clear - DNS won't help here, because after the DNS resolution the computers still connects with IP addresses.

Comment: Do you want the failover to be transparent to the user ?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear exactly what you need.

If two providers merge into one channel with multiple interfaces on a Windows computer, use it [Connectify Dispatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/)

[image: Connectify Dispatch]

or alternative software.

If you need to connect and two ISP at the workstation and you have to switch depending on the operating channel:

/1. delete default gateway:

```
route delete -p 0.0.0.0
```

/2. view network interface:

```
route print | find "0x"
```

/3. add route to ISP 1 and ISP 2

```
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 <ip address NIC1> METRIC <priority ISP1> IF 0x<NIC1>
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 <ip address NIC2> METRIC <priority ISP2> IF 0x<NIC2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your two internet connections as two gateways.

Users can simply execute this command if any of the gateway is down.

```
route del default ;route add default gw <alternate gateway IP>
```